# Problem with Django-dbindexer

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I asked my question in appropriate Google Group (http://groups.google.com/group/django-non-relational/browse_thread/thread/a51c1903af175e1c), but developers seems are kinda busy now, so I'm afraid my question will remain unanswered. Hope I'll find solution of my problem here.

Essense is:
I use Django-nonrel + GAE + Blog App from [Django Basic apps](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps) 
From admin panel of my app I tried to create new blog post. And got the following exception:

```
DatabaseError: Lookup type 'month' isn't supported
```

I asked about this in related google group and was answered to use [django-dbindexer](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-dbindexer).
Regarding it desription it is exactly what I need, so I guided through all instructions and "attached" it to my app. Indexing is done, but I however get the same exception. Here is the full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 308, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\utils\decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 79, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 190, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\utils\decorators.py", line 28, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\utils\decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\utils\decorators.py", line 24, in bound_func
    return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\db\transaction.py", line 282, in inner
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 852, in add_view
    if form.is_valid():
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\forms\forms.py", line 121, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\forms\forms.py", line 112, in _get_errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\forms\forms.py", line 269, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\forms\models.py", line 338, in _post_clean
    self.validate_unique()
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\forms\models.py", line 347, in validate_unique
    self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\db\models\base.py", line 669, in validate_unique
    date_errors = self._perform_date_checks(date_checks)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\db\models\base.py", line 791, in _perform_date_checks
    if qs.exists():
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\db\models\query.py", line 498, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 428, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 222, in has_results
    return self.get_count(check_exists=True)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 269, in get_count
    return self.build_query().count(high_mark)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 275, in build_query
    query.add_filters(self.query.where)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 72, in add_filters
    self.add_filters(child)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 76, in add_filters
    self.add_filter(column, lookup_type, self._negated, db_type, value)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\djangoappengine\db\compiler.py", line 57, in _func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Its_mine19\Programming\Java\pineapplemon\src\djangoappengine\db\compiler.py", line 211, in add_filter
    raise DatabaseError("Lookup type %r isn't supported" % lookup_type)
DatabaseError: Lookup type 'month' isn't supported
```

Here is my data model (from basic.blog.models):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """Post model."""
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, _('Draft')),
        (2, _('Public')),
    )
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(_('body'), )
    tease = models.TextField(_('tease'), blank=True, help_text=_('Concise text suggested. Does not appear in RSS feed.'))
    status = models.IntegerField(_('status'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=2)
    allow_comments = models.BooleanField(_('allow comments'), default=True)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(_('publish'), default=datetime.datetime.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(_('modified'), auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    tags = TagField()
    objects = PublicManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('post')
        verbose_name_plural = _('posts')
        db_table  = 'blog_posts'
        ordering  = ('-publish',)
        get_latest_by = 'publish'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog_detail', None, {
            'year': self.publish.year,
            'month': self.publish.strftime('%b').lower(),
            'day': self.publish.day,
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_previous_post(self):
        return self.get_previous_by_publish(status__gte=2)

    def get_next_post(self):
        return self.get_next_by_publish(status__gte=2)
```

Here is what I have in dbindexes module of my app (basic.blog.dbindexes):

```
from basic.blog.models import Post
from dbindexer.api import register_index



register_index(Post, {
    'publish': 'month',
 #   'created': 'month',
 #   'modified': 'month',
})



import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('Basic.blog dbindexes')    # Logging statement to check if this module is ever executed to be sure indexing is done
```

Thanks in advance for any help.